# Jquery post does not post special characters

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery post request i am making to the server but it does not post special characters for instance `@` for emails. This is the code

```
var ob = {
  'email' : email
};

var data = $.param(ob);
setInterval(function() {
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        crossOrigin: true,
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('.jbalance').html(data);
        },
        error: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
        if(typeof data === 'object'){
        var data = 'No Internet Connection Detected';
        }    
        },
        cache: false,
        processData: false
    });
}, 5 * 1000);
```

This is what is posted `email=cern64%40gmail.com` but i would like `email=cern64@gmail.com`

How can i correct this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`decodeURIComponent`** would help, Replace the below code with yours:

```
var ob = {
  'email' : email
};

var data = decodeURIComponent($.param(ob));
```